# Signing map application android

Tags: android, google-maps, signing

I made my first app on andoid and it's a app with google maps inside. I have read [some articles](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html) and I don't understand it.

I don't have any keystore or keytool. How can I sign my app? What is procedure? Do I first export signed app with option create new keystore and then get new Maps API key and then in my apk file change map key or what?

Here is my debug Maps API key:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
                    android:id="@+id/mapview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"                 
                    android:enabled="false"                                     
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar1" 
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:apiKey="0djE6Z-QX918E3HmDriPn2hxyzFD0kzduhFbiaQ" >              
                </com.google.android.maps.MapView>
```

Comment: See these links, may be helpful: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html, http://androidapps.org.ua/i_sect17_d1e6459.html

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

here is the answer

keytool.exe is on java_jre/bin/keytool.exe